# Your project is not referencing the ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78"

Tags: msbuild, .net-standard

When i build my PCL project i received the following error:

`Microsoft.NuGet.targets(186, 5): [null] Your project is not referencing the ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78" framework. Add a reference to ".NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78" in the "frameworks" section of your project.json, and then re-run NuGet restore.`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Following error appears when you have .netstandard project in same directory and build it once.
It leaves .json files in `Obj` directory and it breaks PCL project build.

Move .netstandard .csproj out of this directory and remove `Bin` and `Obj` directories.

Comment: This happened in my case of switching a PCL project to .netstandard project and then switched back.

Comment: Thank you! I had an issue, and removed the obj files that were recently created. Also I had to remove a created project.json.locked and then it started working.

Comment: I do not have project.json but do have project.assets.json. I do not have provision to move this project out of directory. any other solution is highly appreciated.